# How to eject using expo managed workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently using the expo managed workflow with react native. I want to eject my project so that I have more freedom. From my research it looks like "ejecting" may not be a thing anymore and it is instead called "prebuilding". I already "prebuilt" my project but don't see that anything has really changed. I want to be able to configure some things using native code and most other things using typescript. How do I change my current project to allow myself to do that?

Comment: running `npx expo prebuild` generates your ios and android projects (ios and android directories). you now have full control over everything in your project. if it looks the same after running it, great, prebuild worked well!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to eject anymore. You can use virtually any native code using Expo EAS and config plugins. Expo's Managed Workflow restricting the "freedom" is very much a thing of the past. Some third-party libraries even provide their own config plugins. Even if they don't, it's not really hard to write them yourself using the installation guide of the library you want to use and the [documentation on config plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/introduction/).

When you use custom native code with such config plugins, the only downside is that you won't be able to use Expo Go anymore. However, you're able to build your "own version" of Expo Go with your native code included using Expo EAS called a [development client](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/).

This way, you can of course also add your own native code.

However, if this somehow doesn't appeal to you, you can absolutely "prebuild" the app instead. When you do so, Expo will generate `ios` and `android` directories within your project with all native code included.